# How can I get tSQLt tests to show up in Visual Studio's Test Explorer?

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-data-tools, tsqlt

I can't seem to get my tSQLt test to show up in Visual Studio Test Explorer.

I have a database project (SSDT) that contains my database that I want to test against. I also have another database project in the solution that is named the same as the main database project but has `.Tests` appended to the end of the name. The `.Tests` project contains a database reference to the main database project.

I ran the install script for tSQLt in the database and can see all the stored procedures for tSQLt in the database.

I have installed the [tSQLt test adapter](https://the.agilesql.club/blogs/Ed-Elliott/tSQLt-Visual-Studio-Test-Adapter) extension from Visual Studio's Extensions and Updates dialog. I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Update 3.

I created a `.runsettings` file and selected it by going to `Test > Test Settings > Select Test Settings File` as the adapter instructions state. Here are the contents of that file (I removed the connection string details in this post but I have verified my connection string works elsewhere):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RunSettings>
  <TestRunParameters>
    <Parameter name="TestDatabaseConnectionString" value="Server=MySqlServer;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI" />
    <Parameter name="IncludePath" value="Tests" />
  </TestRunParameters>
</RunSettings>
```

When I build the solution, I don't see any tests in the Test Explorer window. Any ideas on what I can try to fix this?

Comment: On the disk are the tests in a subfolder called "Tests"? That is what the IncludePath bit is saying.

Comment: @EdElliott On the disk? I'm not sure what you mean by that. My `.Tests` project contains a subfolder called `Tests` that has all my tests in it if that is what you mean. Thanks for taking time to respond.

Comment: Can you put a demo of a project that doesn't work on github or email it to me ed.elliott outlook com and I'll take a look

Comment: @EdElliott I'm not sure what I did before that caused it not to work. I created a new example from scratch to upload to GitHub to show you...and now it is working. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @EdElliott I'm having a new issue. Please take a look at my new question if you have time: http://stackoverflow.com/q/44053420/4416750.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what I was doing wrong before, but I created the projects again from scratch and everything is working now.