# Why does a tSQLt test pass in Visual Studio Test Explorer when it should fail?

Tags: sql-server, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-data-tools, tsqlt

I'm writing some tSQLt tests and running them using Visual Studio's Test Explorer via the [tSQLt test adapter](https://the.agilesql.club/blogs/Ed-Elliott/tSQLt-Visual-Studio-Test-Adapter) extension. I'm doing [TDD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development), so I'm writing the test before writing the stored procedure that it tests.

The problem is, when I run the test, it should fail because the stored procedure does not exist yet. When I run the test with tSQLt in Sql Server Management Studio it fails like it should:

```
The module 'test_ValidCustomerName_CustomerIdIs1' depends on the missing object 'dbo.AddCustomer'. The module will still be created; however, it cannot run successfully until the object exists.

(0 row(s) affected)
[AddCustomer].[test_ValidCustomerName_CustomerIdIs1] failed: (Error) Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.AddCustomer'.[16,62]{test_ValidCustomerName_CustomerIdIs1,7}

+----------------------+
|Test Execution Summary|
+----------------------+

|No|Test Case Name                                      |Dur(ms)|Result|
+--+----------------------------------------------------+-------+------+
|1 |[AddCustomer].[test_ValidCustomerName_CustomerIdIs1]|      0|Error |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Msg 50000, Level 16, State 10, Line 1
Test Case Summary: 1 test case(s) executed, 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 errored.
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

But when I run it in Test Explorer, it says the test passes:

[image: test explorer screenshot]

Here is the code for the test:

```
EXEC tSQLt.NewTestClass 'AddCustomer';
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE AddCustomer.test_ValidCustomerName_CustomerIdIs1
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @customerName   NVARCHAR(40)    = 'John Doe'

    EXEC dbo.AddCustomer @customerName

    DECLARE @expected   INT     = 1
          , @actual     INT     = (SELECT CustomerID
                                   FROM dbo.Customer
                                   WHERE Name = @customerName)

    EXEC tSQLt.AssertEquals @expected, @actual
END
GO
```

And here is the `dbo.Customer` table:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Customer
(
    CustomerID  INT             NOT NULL    PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 1)
  , Name        NVARCHAR(50)    NOT NULL
)
```

**EDIT** - I've modified the test to just call `tSQLt.Fail`:

```
EXEC tSQLt.NewTestClass 'AddCustomer';
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE AddCustomer.test_ValidCustomerName_CustomerIdIs1
AS
BEGIN   
    EXEC tSQLt.Fail 'Test should fail'
END
GO
```

The test still fails in Sql Server Management Studio but it **passes** in Test Explorer.

Comment: Hey Lews - I have tried this exact thing and it works for me - can you tell me the version of SQL Server and Visual Studio you are using?

Comment: @EdElliott Thanks for taking a look. I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 and Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise Update 3.

Answer (score 1):

I have updated the test adapter to visual studio 2017 and fixed a couple of issues. I ran this code here and can't reproduce it (the tests cause a failure in visual studio).

Grab the latest version from:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-263684.tSQLtTestAdapterforVisualStudio2017

If you need vs 2015 support let me know, I am hesitant as it means maintaining two versions.

ed